# How To Add Widget In Storyboard Type In XCode, Swift5 project

Tags: xcode, swiftui, widget, storyboard, swift5

This Is how i am adding widget file in my project.
.
.
.

[image: How I'm Adding Widget]

i have storyboard project which use swift5 as programming language,
but when i add widget it automatically add Widget with SwiftUI concept Which is not Working Im Project.

.
.
.

[image: WhiftUI Widget Looks Like.]
.
.
.

I’m thankful to you if you provide valuable solution.

Comment: To my knowledge Widget Kits can only build with SwiftUI. This in.formation is from the WWDC2020 and Intro to WidgetKit videos.

Comment: Is there any other way? i mean leaning swiftUI is compulsory ? to develop widgets?

Comment: SwiftUI is the leading direction and widgets are a new feature, so to integrated it there is only a view in the future technical platform. You may call it compulsory ..... I found Storyboard even as complex as SwiftUI to learn...... But .to answer: I don't know another way.

Comment: Ive heard of some people using the old "Today" but it is hardly worth the the effort to be outdated.